# R Probability calculation with number of Criterion

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, mathematical-optimization, probability-theory

I have historic data with 4 constraints  say C1, C2, C3 and C4 . All the constraints take string value.
If we take an example of a football match say 4 constraints would be

```
C1 :place where game is taking place (USA,IND,AUS etc) 
C2 : Month (jan , feb ..)
C3 :start time (9am , 10 am , 9pm , 10pm..)
C4 : Playing against team (Chelsa , juventus ..)
```

I have historic data with different values in all constraint and the result of the game, so I have a huge collection of data like following :

```
C1  C2  C3  C4        result
USA Jan 9AM Chelsa    Won
USA Jan 7PM juventus  Won
IND Feb 8PM Barcelona Lost
UK  May 6AM juventus  Lost
AU  Nov 5AM Barcelona Won
HK  Oct 2PM Chelsa    Won
```

Now based on this data I want to calculate the probability of wining if my team have a match with Chelsa in USA in Jan at 7pm.

I have lots and lots of data, but not sure if I'll find a record which exactly matches my requirement. In that case how will I calculate the probability if my C1, C2, C3, C4 does not match any of the records, but I have some records with C1, C2, C3 matching some with C2, C3, C4 matching ..and so on...?

Can someone give me any direction on how to proceed.

Comment: This sounds like more of a statistical modeling problem than an R programming problem. You would probably be better off asking this question at [stats.se] or [datascience.se] for help deciding how you want to model your data.